# Gnome 3 native elements too small

Tags: linux, gnome3, gnome-shell

I am using manjaro, gnome 3. Previously I had i3 installed too.

My gnome native app widgets are too small, for some apps (nautilus) left side file tree area fonts are too small too. Affects only proper gnome apps - files, videos, tweaks, gedit and very annoyingly - gnome-terminal. My display is hdpi (2880x1620), gnome scaling is 200%. But even if I put scaling to 300% even then widgets are notably too small.

Some other apps - like google-chrome and calibre have their widgets just fine.
No application of themes seems to change this behaviour.

Compare top bar of normal widgets (chrome) with the size of buttons below (nautilus) - I placed windows overlapping for the screenshot to show the problem:

[image: normal chrome, small nautilus]

Also some things are strangely squished to the middle (settings) and fonts/icons are small:

[image: settings squished]

- What could be causing this behaviour and how to fix it?
- Maybe there is a way to reset this?
- Are there scaling factors that pertain to only gnome apps?

Comment: I happened to get a different laptop, of course - on a fresh installation everything was fine. But then we get into the windows world (just kidding) - when something goes wrong, reinstall... I still haven't got the cause, but some updates made this bearable.